# How to specify the range of all rows containing data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

What is the syntax for selecting the full range of rows which contain data?

Say for instance I have 200 rows of data.  Im running some functions which loop through rows. If I wanted to select the range of these rows manually from column A, I would write is as A1:A200.
But is there a way to write it from "A1" : "last row in the column A that contains an entry"

Alternatively is there a way to write A1:"end of column A, regardless of entries"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `A1:A` to get the entire column, or `A1:Z` to get a range of columns. In Apps Script, you can call [sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) (or [sheet.getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)) to get the last row containing data and use that to write your loops.

References

- [sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [sheet.getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the use of [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()).This method returns a Range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present.